# swift - how to cast Any as other class and assign generic type

Tags: swift, generics, casting

I have an generic type class A

```
class A<T> {
....
}
```

And other class B have some properties type is A

```
class B {
var propOne: A<String>
var propTwo: A<Int>
...
}
```

now use `Mirror` scan all properties and I need to cast value as `A`

```
var mineB = B(...)
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: mineB)
for case let (label?, value) in mirror.children {
    ...
    let objA = value as? A
}
```

But have compiler error is `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'CSRObject<_>'`

It's OK when update `let objA = value as? A<Swift.String>`

But It mean I compare all type

How method let me fast cast?

Comment: A<String> and A<Int> are two completely different types. There is no way you can directly cast to A.